# Restrict button from being clicked based on the time of the day ANDROID

Tags: java, android, time

I need a way to restrict a button from being clicked in my android app based on the time of day. For instance I need the app to not place orders after 9pm, so I want to disable the button after that time. I've looked into in it and saw "Time now = new Time();" there is an after method that says it takes a time input. I tried 900, 9:00 and 9:00pm with no luck, does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: joda time, DateTime.now() and check if now > 9pm: disable it; enable it. All this in onResume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with Joda time is a bit limited so i'm not sure if exists better ways, but that's how i would do it

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

if (now.getHourOfDay() >= 21)
{
    System.out.println("Disable it.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Enable it.");
}
```

The same could be done with the Java API

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 21)
{
    System.out.println("Diasble it.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Enable it.");
}
```

But if you need to work with dates/etc. you could start to use JodaTime.

It will be enabled from `0 - 21`, disabled from `21 - 23`

Use this code inside `onResume`

Comment: Thanks Marco appreciate your help!